# Save list as file in python (The file should be accepted in other programming languages as well )

Tags: python

I have a 3 dimensional list of int8 datatype and I want to save it to a txt file. How can i save the file such that the  value are saved as int8 not as string which will reduce txt file size. I am doing in python

Comment: By definition, a text file is a file that contains strings. A file that contains values of other data types is a binary file. Do you want a text file or a binary file?

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "`int8` datatype" does not exist in Python (as a builtin type at least), and means absolutely nothing to the filesystem. And if you're concerned with file size, then you definitly want some kind of database (not necessarly a relational one).

Comment: How big is this file going to be?

Comment: The size of the list is about 6MB ..... it could be saved as csv or any format(except pickle) but main thing is size need to be reduced

Comment: You wanted to save a _text file_ as a pile of _integers_ for _6MB_? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I want to save it in any format where i can reduce file size ... the file should be recognized in other platforms not only in python.... thanks for commenting out the mistake in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to save space, you need to store your data in binary format. This can be achieved with the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example) module.

For instance, let's save a list of 1000 integers both in binary and text formats:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> import pickle
>>> l = [randint(0, 100000) for i in range(0, 1000)]
>>> bf = open("out.bin", "wb") # binary file
>>> tf = open("out.txt", "w")  # ASCII file
>>> pickle.dump(l, bf, -1) # write file with highest possible protocol (binary)
>>> for i in l:
...     tf.write(str(i) + " ")
>>> bf.close()
>>> tf.close()
```

The binary file weights 3.7 kb vs 5.8 kb for the text file:

```
$ ls -lh out*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 regis regis 3,7K janv. 18 10:16 out.bin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 regis regis 5,8K janv. 18 10:14 out.txt
```

If your objective is to reduce the file size and read the file back in a different language (or a different OS), then there are many solutions that are more efficient than to serialize to a binary format. You simply have a problem of file compression. Writing to a gzip-compressed file is easy in python, and reading from gzip-compressed files is pretty standard, so you should find appropriate libraries in your target language.

Here is how to write a 128*128*128 list to a gzip compressed file:

```
l = [randint(0, 100000) for _ in range(0, 128*128*128)]
with gzip.open("out.txt.gz", "w") as tfz:
    tfz.write(" ".join([str(i) for i in l]))
```

This results in a **5.5 Mb binary file**, vs a 12 Mb uncompressed text file and a 7.4 Mb binary file produced by `pickle`.

Comment: I tried to dump as you said but it is taking lot of time... I  am novice at these thing ... What i want to have is a LUT where data[a][b][c] will yeild (x,y,z) so size of LUT is 128*128*128 ...i have 3D list of size 7 MB approx and need to save it to a file and later used by loading in anothere program . I cannot pickle it as i need the file in another non-python program also

Comment: Beeing able to read it in a non-python program is a quite important part of the problem statement. Include that in the question

Comment: @SandeepNeupane did I address your question? How did you finally solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry i have been busy few days ... the size is less than 6MB so it should work for me ..i will check it and get back to you ...Thanks for the help !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a file are by definition a string. You can you use either pickles or json.

```
import json

data = []

fl = open('myfile', 'wb')
fl.write(json.dumps(data))
fl.close()
```

And when you read the file from python you will also have to load the json with `json.loads()`. Pickle works the same way.

edit:

As for a way to reduce the size - I'm afraid you will have to use some sort of compression. If you need performance, you might want to look into [python-blosc](http://python-blosc.blosc.org/).

Comment: Advising someone seeking to reduce the size of their file to use JSON is actually quite counterproductive. This will make their file larger, not smaller.

Comment: ahem... you might want to use `json.dump` and avoid handling the file

Comment: yole :: Exactly my point i can save it as above but the size get huge as data is saved as string i need it to be saved as integer .....

Comment: @SandeepNeupane this is precisely the problem: no matter what you do, once you create a file and store data in it, it becomes a string. Python has no way of knowing how to treat a string when it sees it and this, as soon as you start reading the file you have to make one manipulation or another to convert it back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save binary file as a .txt file, you could use [Base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) encoding. The overhead is around 33% (three bytes of binary are stored as four ASCII characters), but it'll be a text file.

Have you considered compression for size reduction?

Answer (score 0):

You got excellent answers already, but here is another (raw) solution for a minimum footprint.

It assumes the number of elements in each dimension of the matrix is constant (e.g. dictated by the size of the first element) and it fits in one byte (i.e. less than 256 elements per dimension, but it can be increased easily)

```
import struct

lst=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]

g = (bytearray(r) for c in lst for r in c)

with open('mtxints.bin', 'wb') as f:
    # python 2/3
    f.write(struct.pack('@B', len(lst)))
    f.write(struct.pack('@B', len(lst[0])))
    f.write(struct.pack('@B', len(lst[0][0])))

    # python 3 only
    # f.write(bytes([len(lst)]))
    # f.write(bytes([len(lst[0])]))
    # f.write(bytes([len(lst[0][0])]))
    for a in g:
        f.write(a)
print(' saved', lst)

with open('mtxints.bin', 'rb') as f:
    # python 2/3
    x = struct.unpack('@B', f.read(1))[0]
    y = struct.unpack('@B', f.read(1))[0]
    z = struct.unpack('@B', f.read(1))[0]

    # python 3 only
    # x = int.from_bytes(f.read(1), byteorder='big', signed=False)
    # y = int.from_bytes(f.read(1), byteorder='big', signed=False)
    # z = int.from_bytes(f.read(1), byteorder='big', signed=False)
    print('matrix dimensions', x, y, z)
    newlst = []
    for a in range(x):
        newb = []
        for b in range(y):
            c = bytearray(f.read(z))
            newb.append(list(map(int, c)))
        newlst.append(newb)

print('loaded', lst)
```

which produces (on python2 you may get odd printouts, use `print` without `()`)

```
 saved [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
matrix dimensions 2 2 3
loaded [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

and a file of 15 bytes: 3 for the header (one for each dimension) and 12 for the contents

```
mbb@dev:~/SO/py$ ll mtxints.bin 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mbb mbb 15 gen 18 11:13 mtxints.bin

mbb@dev:~/SO/py$ xxd mtxints.bin
0000000: 0202 0301 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c    ...............
```

Basically the program writes the size of each dimension into a the file header, one at a time.

Then it writes the contents of the matrix by using a generator that iterates on the second dimension and yields the elements of the third dimension as chunks of bytes.

When loading the matrix back form the file, it reads the size of each dimension from the header and uses those to iterate on the first two dimensions to read the right number of bytes for the contents of the third.

As I said, it's a pretty raw solution, hard-coded for three dimensions, but you get the idea.

Please see [struct.pack/unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) for more info

Comment: can you explain how above program works
and i get error 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_bytes' while running the code

Comment: Yes my python version on 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Write the data as csv and then gzip it.
At the other end gunzip it and then process the data.
See the python gzip entry:https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

```
>>> import gzip
>>> import shutil
>>> with open('file.txt', 'rb') as file_input, gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb', 9) as file_output:
...     shutil.copyfileobj(file_input,file_output)
...
```